# R e1071 trains faster than Libsvm

Tags: c, r, performance, libsvm

I am trying to use nu and epsilon SVR in library Libsvm in C after trying to use it in R (package e1071). But training time differs too much, in R it took less than a sec to generate my model, and in C it took more than 2 minutes. Is this a normal behavior?

In C I am running it like this:

./svm-train -s 3 -t 0 -q series.train series.model

I have tried giving more paramters, using more cache memory, and adding -fopenmp flag to compilation (it added about 10 extra secs to running time).

Any hint would be appreciated!

Edit:
My training file:

```
5.7367 1:1
5.46076 1:2
4.80722 1:3
4.80722 1:4
4.64745 1:5
4.66924 1:6
4.52401 1:7
4.76364 1:8
4.06652 1:9
4.03748 1:10
...
...
...
64.02734 1:1999
63.6241 1:2000
```

It is supposed to be a financial time series, the first column is the close price of the stock, and the first index is just a numerical value in increasing order (instead of the date).

R Code:

```
data<-read.csv("/home/manzha/series/GCARSO.csv",header=TRUE)
X <- c(1:2310) # 2310 is the total of rows
trainL<-2000
X_train <- c(1:trainL)
X_test <- c((trainL+1):length(X))
Y_test<-data$Adj.Close[(trainL+1):length(X)]
Y_train <- data$Adj.Close[1:trainL]
DF <- data.frame(x = X_train, y = Y_train)
model <- svm(y ~ x, data = DF, kernel= "linear", cost=2, epsilon=0.5, type="eps-regression")
predictedY <- predict(model, newdata= data.frame(x= X_test))
```

I have read some of the e1071 library doc and it scales the data automatically. I have tried scalling my data and it takes no time in training! But the results differ from R.
If I write:

```
model <- svm(y ~ x, data = DF, kernel= "linear", cost=2, epsilon=0.5, type="eps-regression",scale=FALSE)
```

R takes more time doing the training almost the same than C libsvm, and it gives the same result.

*So for now, I think that my problem is how my training and test file after scaling are written.*

Comment: how large is your data set? are the vectors sparse (i.e. a lot of zeros)? Are you using a linear kernel?

Comment: My data set is about 2300 rows and I took about 2000 for the training set. It is not sparse (or I think it is not), and the svm is epsilon SVR with linear kernel. I'll try to edit my question to put some of rows of my training file (as I had trouble with its format)

Comment: How many features?

Comment: I added a summary of my training file, I guess the number of features would be one (the number of indexes), isn't it?

Comment: Yes one. OK interesting. Seems e1071 is also using libsvm. Are you sure it is also using the same type? (-s 3). You should probably post the exact R code you are using.

Comment: The svm function is: model <- svm(y ~ x, data = DF, kernel= "linear", cost=2, epsilon=0.5, type="eps-regression"). And  DF is DF <- data.frame(x = X_train, y = Y_train). I do not have all my R code in order right now, so I will post it later (I'll edit my post again).

Comment: I added the R Code, and found why it took so long, but still can't have the same results. I'm not sure if I should write how did I solve the main problem as an answer instead of the same post

Comment: nice. A separate answer is the right thing to do.